# Tag place types in google map street-view api

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm new to **Google Maps API** and using **streetview**.

I want to display the tag in each place in streetview the once I screenshot.

*(see there is orange and blue tag eg. restaurant, cafe, clothing store)*

*as per **Mr. Upsidedown**, added  working API key which is free for use on Stack overflow.*

[image]

I was able to pin some places type using the `Places API` and it pin on maps but did not pin on streetview.

```js
var map;

function createMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326 },
    zoom: 20
  });

  var request = {
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 8047,
    types: ['cafe']
  }

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  
  const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById("pano"),
        {
            position: map.getCenter(),
            pov: {
                heading: 34,
                pitch: 10,
            },
        }
    );
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log(results.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    title: place.name
  })
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map,
#pano {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="pano"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=createMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the markers to be visible on both the map and on Street View, just create the markers on `map` and `panorama`.

See my comments in the code. I also modified the center point and pano heading so that a Marker is in view when loaded.

```js
var map;
var panorama; // Added this so that panorama is in global scope

function createMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: 42.344268, lng: -71.101617 },
    zoom: 20
  });

  var request = {
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 8047,
    types: ['cafe']
  }

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  
  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById("pano"),
        {
            position: map.getCenter(),
            pov: {
                heading: 65,
                pitch: 10,
            },
        }
    );
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log(results.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    title: place.name
  });
  
  // added this to also add the Marker on panorama
  var marker_pano = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: panorama,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    title: place.name
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map,
#pano {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="pano"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=createMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: This is great thank you. But how can I can make visible those default markers like the one on the screenshot ( there restaurant icon tags, hotel icon tags etc). Ive been scanning all the Google developer documents but haven't seen one how to display those. Thanks

Comment: These are called *POI* and AFAIK you can't display them in Street View. What you see on Google Maps website isn't always available through the API.

Comment: Thanks for giving me those terms and clarifications. Now I understand it isn't part of the API. Take my upvote

Comment: The way you did it (request to the Places API / display your own Markers) is the way to do it atm. It would be an interesting feature though so I opened a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190633725) in the issue tracker. You can star the issue to be notified if Google decides to implement it.

Comment: I already starred the issue bug tracker. That's a nice feature if it will be added.